# how to show the mesh in terrain or others in ogre，

Tags: mesh, ogre

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcOxx.jpg

Look at the picture, I want to achieve something like this in OGRE, but I have no idea about this.

I am trying to make a SLG game with OGRE now, and the first step is to show the mesh.

I am a Chinese student and it's... My English grade is not good, and in my country I can only find a little doc about OGRE. The internet is filled with Unity3D... I thank for everybody who has read my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## One way

Add to your object's .material script one more pass.

```
material myMaterial
{
    technique
    {
        pass solidPass
        {
            // sets your object's colour, texture etc.
            // ... leave what you have here

            polygon_mode solid // sets to render the object as a solid

        }

        pass wireframePass
        {
            diffuse 0 0 0 1.0 // the colour of the wireframe (white)
            polygon_mode wireframe // sets to render the object as a wireframe
        }
    }
}
```

This of course renders the object twice, but I assume it's just for debugging purposes and the lines are quite slim, also the object overlaps the wireframe at some parts.

## The usual way

Add another texture_unit to the object's .material script that contains thin white squares of size the same as in the UV mapping (which you can export with most modelling software) with a transparent background

Make sure the .material script has alpha enabled in the pass you created

```
scene_blend alpha_blend
scene_blend_op add
```

This lets you choose what kind of lines you want.

### Source:

Also check the [OGRE Manual](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/manual_toc.html#SEC_Contents) under Material Scripts. It goes much more in depth about the material script itself

Comment: that's wonderful,thanks for you help.                                                            another question:Ogre2.1 is stable in linux and windows,it's much more faster than 1.9. Is the 2.1material part same as 1.9?

Comment: @luoyi I'm not sure. But if you're just beginning with Ogre I would advise to avoid the 2.1 version for now and use the 1.9. Most code snippets on the [Ogre3D Tutorials](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Tutorials) page will produce errors in the 2.1 version and it will be much harder to learn the engine.